# Как из 1с в xml

Tags: xml, 1с

Есть база 1С.

Как мне сохранить всю эту базу в один документ формата xml?

Comment: Написать обработку (http://howknow1c.ru/programmirovanie-1c/obrabotki-1s.html)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще говоря, никак.
Нужно уточнить, что требуется, база с данными, данные, или база как текст конфигурации?

1. Если база с данными вместе, то проще работать на уровне СУБД, то есть развернуть базу в клиент-серверном режиме на, допустим, MS SQL сервер и выгружать базу SQL
2. Если только данные, то в конфигурации "конвертация данных" (есть на диске ИТС) готовим правила обмена с идентичной конфигурацией, делаем выгрузку. Для части типовых конфигураций такие правила есть
3. Если только конфигурацию (код) то в режиме конфигуратора есть команда "Выгрузить конфигурацию в файлы"
4. Есть проект "v83unpack", распаковывает не только код, но и всю структуру конфигурации в текстовые файлы
   Последние два пункта создают не один XML, а множество текстовых файлов.

Comment: Добавлю по пункту 2. Можно обойтись без "приготовления" правил обмена, если использовать обработку ВыгрузкаЗагрузкаДанныхXML, которую можно взять либо на том же диске ИТС, либо в составе файлов установленного шаблона конфигурации "Конвертация данных" (в папке с шаблонами). Можно выгрузить полностью все данные или по установленному отбору.